# API for operators and alerts

Tags: api, database, devops, fastapi

Note: The important chunks of code are pasted in the question but the larger representation of the app is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/blackdead263/fastapireview).

Some time ago I was tasked to create a simple FastAPI app. I did manage to pull it off and I already have it running with no errors, But I want to improve it. This project has a lot in common with a simple blog app, where an author (an `operator`) can write posts (`alert`s).
In this project I use `FastAPI`, `SQLAlchemy`, `pydantic`, `alembic`, `uvicorn`, `pytest`, and `passlib`

My main questions are:

- Is this app suitable for the production phase?
- Am I using industry-standard routines and functions?
- Is the code pythonic?
- Are schemas/models correct? Are their responsibilities distributed well?
- Does the app follow SOLID principles? Does it even need to (considering its small scale)?

My goals for this project are:

- be scalable with a predictable structure and readable clean code (**my main goal**),
- have database models/schemas that make sense, and are maintainable for possible future modifications,
- dockerize,
- connect to a React front-end and a PostgreSQL database, and
- run automated tests.

*(NOTE: the actual app - fully or partially - already includes the last three items, but I welcome any suggestions.)*

Future plans:

- have JWT authorization
- have roles for `operator`s with different permissions
- run on a server

I appreciate any comments (even opinionated ones on the design  of this app).

---

Here is my code:

***main.py***

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from app.apis.base import api_router
from app.db.base import Base
from app.db.session import engine

app = FastAPI()

# Create all database tables
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

# Include API router
app.include_router(api_router)


@app.get("/")
def health_check():
    return {"message": "Health: Check"}
```

---

***schemas.py***

```
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy import JSON
from .operator import ShowOperator
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr, Field
from datetime import datetime

class CreateAlert(BaseModel):
    showAlert: bool | None = False
    alertContent: str
    androidVersion: str | None = ""
    launcherVersion: str | None = ""
    releaseDate: datetime | None = datetime.utcnow()


class ShowAlert(BaseModel):
    id: int
    showAlert: bool
    alertContent: str
    androidVersion: str
    launcherVersion: str
    releaseDate: datetime
    lastUpdate: datetime
    author: ShowOperator
    author_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UpdateAlert(CreateAlert):
    lastUpdate: datetime | None = datetime.utcnow()


class CreateOperator(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: str = Field(..., min_length=4)
    fullName: str
    phoneNumber: str
    accessLevel: str | None = "audit"
    createdDate: str | None = datetime.utcnow()


class ShowOperator(BaseModel):
    id: int
    email: EmailStr
    accessLevel: str
    fullName: str
    phoneNumber: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UpdateOperator(CreateOperator):
    pass
```

---

***models.py***

```
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from ...db.base_class import Base
from datetime import datetime
from enum import Enum

class Alert(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    showAlert = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    alertContent = Column(String, nullable=False)
    androidVersion = Column(String, nullable=False)
    launcherVersion = Column(String, nullable=False)
    releaseDate = Column(DateTime, nullable=False,)
    lastUpdate = Column(DateTime)
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("operator.id"))
    author = relationship("Operator", back_populates="alerts")


class AccessLevel(str, Enum):
    audit = "audit"
    content = "content"
    manager = "manager"


class Operator(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    fullName = Column(String)
    isLoggedIn = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    phoneNumber = Column(String)
    createdDate = Column(DateTime)
    accessLevel = Column(String)  # enum!
    alerts = relationship(
        "Alert", back_populates="author", cascade="all, delete")
```

---

***API v1 route, alert repo functions***

```
from typing import List

from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException, status
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from ...db.repo.alert import (
    create_new_alert,
    delete_alert,
    retreive_alert,
    retreive_all_alerts,
    update_alert,
)
from ...db.session import get_db
from ...schemas.alert import CreateAlert, ShowAlert, UpdateAlert

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/alerts", response_model=ShowAlert, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_one_alert(alert: CreateAlert, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    alert = create_new_alert(alert=alert, db=db, author_id=1)
    return alert

@router.get("/alert/{id}", response_model=ShowAlert)
def get_one_alert(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    alert = retreive_alert(id=id, db=db)
    if not alert:
        raise HTTPException(
            detail=f"Alert with ID {id} does not exist.",
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        )
    return alert

@router.get("/alerts/all", response_model=List[ShowAlert])
def get_all_alerts(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    alerts = retreive_all_alerts(db=db)
    return alerts

@router.put("/alert/{id}", response_model=ShowAlert)
def update_one_alert(id: int, alert: UpdateAlert, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    alert = update_alert(id=id, alert=alert, author_id=1, db=db)
    if not alert:
        raise HTTPException(
            detail=f"Alert with id {id} does not exist",
            tatus_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        )
    return alert

@router.delete("/alert/{id}")
def delete_one_alert(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    message = delete_alert(id=id, author_id=1, db=db)
    if message.get("error"):
        raise HTTPException(
            detail=message.get("error"), status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
    return {"msg": f"Successfully deleted alert with id {id}"}
```

---

***API v1 route, operator repo functions***

```
from typing import List

from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException, status
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from ...db.repo.operator import (
    create_new_operator,
    delete_operator,
    retreive_all_operators,
    retreive_operator,
    update_operator,
)
from ...db.session import get_db
from ...schemas.operator import CreateOperator, ShowOperator, UpdateOperator

router = APIRouter()


@router.post("/operators", response_model=ShowOperator, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_one_operator(operator: CreateOperator, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    operator = create_new_operator(operator=operator, db=db)
    return operator


@router.get("/operator/{id}", response_model=ShowOperator)
def get_one_operator(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    operator = retreive_operator(id=id, db=db)
    if not operator:
        raise HTTPException(
            detail=f"Operator with ID {id} does not exist.", status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    return operator


@router.get("/operators/all", response_model=List[ShowOperator])
def get_all_operators(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    operators = retreive_all_operators(db=db)
    return operators


@router.put("/operator/{id}", response_model=ShowOperator)
def update_one_operator(id: int, operator: UpdateOperator, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    operator = update_operator(id=id, operator=operator, db=db)
    if not operator:
        raise HTTPException(detail=f"Operator with id {id} does not exist")
    return operator


@router.delete("/operator/{id}")
def delete_one_operator(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    message = delete_operator(id=id, db=db)
    if message.get("error"):
        raise HTTPException(detail=message.get("error"),
                            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return {"msg": f"Successfully deleted operator with id {id}"}
```